# Simple method to solve a geometry question for junior high school student

Tags: geometry, optimization

Rencently, my sister asked me a geometry question that came from her mock examination, please see the following graph.

[image]

Here,

- $\angle DOE=45°$
- the length of $DE$ is constant, and $DE=1$. Namely, $OD,OE$ are changeable.
- $\triangle DEF$ is equilateral triangle.

> Q: What is the maximum length of $OF$?

---

#### My solution

Denote $OD,OE,\angle ODE$ as $x,y,\theta$, respectively.

Via sine theorem
$$
  \begin{cases}
    ED^{2} = OE^{2} + OD^{2} - 2OE \times OD\cos \angle EOD \\[6pt]
    \cos \theta = \dfrac{EO^{2} + ED^{2} - OD^{2}}{2 EO \times ED}
  \end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
  1^{2} &= x^{2} + y^{2} - 2xy\cos 45^{\circ} \\
  &= x^{2} + y^{2} - \sqrt{2} xy
\end{align}
$$
$$
  \implies
  \begin{cases}
    \color{red}{xy} = \dfrac{x^{2} + y^{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2}} \color{red}{\leq}
    \dfrac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{2} \implies x^{2} + y^{2} \color{red}{\leq}
    2 + \sqrt{2} \\[6pt]
    \cos \theta = \dfrac{x^{2} + 1 - y^{2}}{2x}
  \end{cases}
$$

Via cosine theorem
$$
  \frac{y}{\sin \theta} = \frac{DE}{\sin \angle EOD} = \frac{1}{\sin
    45^{\circ}} \implies \sin \theta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
$$\begin{align}
  OF^{2} &= EO^{2} + EF^{2} - 2EO \times EF\cos \angle OEF \\
  &= x^{2} + 1^{2} - 2x\cos(\theta + 60^{\circ}) \\
  &= x^{2} + 1 - 2x(\cos \theta \cos 60^{\circ} - \sin \theta \sin
    60^{\circ}) \\
  &= x^{2} + 1 - 2x\left(\frac{x^{2} + 1 - y^{2}}{2x} \frac{1}{2} -
    \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \\
  &= \frac{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3} xy}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  &= \frac{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}
    \frac{x^{2} + y^{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  &= \frac{(\sqrt{3} + 1)(x^{2} + y^{2})}{2} + \frac{1 - \sqrt{3}}{2}
  \\
  &\color{red}{\leq} \frac{(\sqrt{3} + 1)(2 + \sqrt{2})}{2} + \frac{1 -
    \sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(3 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6})
\end{align}
$$

However, for **junior high school student**, she doesn't learn the following formulae:

- sine theorem
- cosine therem
- $\cos(x+y)=\cos x \cos y-\sin x \sin y$
- fundamental inequality $x y\leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$

#### Question

- Is there other **simple/elegant** method to solve this geometry question?

---

#### Update

Thanks for [MXYMXY](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/310930/mxymxy)'s hint

[image]

Here, the line $O'F$ pass **the center of the circle**. Namely, $O'D=OF$

In **Rt** $\triangle O'OF$, the inequality $O'F>OF$ holds.

Comment: Is $DF$ parallel to $OE$ ?

Comment: @imranfat, No, $DF$ is not parallel to $OE$:)

Comment: Well, I am stumped then, because when using GeomSketchpad, I think that the position of the equiliateral triangle is not unique, but someone else gives a hint to a solution which I obviously do not see.

Comment: @imranfat Owing to the length of $OE$ is constant, so I think the **equiliateral triangle** is  unique.

Comment: Ok, if $OE$ is constant and you also say that $DE$ is constant, why isn't $OE=1$ ?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I think you mean that $DE$ is constant. Without that, you cannot solve the problem.

Comment: @imranfat Basically, I thought that the question was as follows. $\triangle DEF$ is equilateral. There is a non-fixed point $O$ for which $\angle DOE$ is $45°$ (and appears to be on a different side of the side $DE$ compared to $F$). Find the maximum length of $FO$.  The answer below seems to be using that the collection of such $O$ would be a circle.

Comment: @imranfat Yes, $OD,OE$ is changeable, but the $DE$ owns the fixed length $1$.

Comment: Tough nut to crack...

Comment: @imranfat  Isn't the answer below correct?

Comment: I am not saying that the answer below isn't correct. There are 3 upvotes and so that looks promising. I am just not comprehending the uniqueness of the position of the equilateral triangle with both $OD$ and $OE$ variable and $DF$ not being parallel. In my sketch I can "rotate" the triangle in such a way that $x$ is decreasing and $y$ is increasing without changing the $45$ angle. It would be awesome if that keep the length $OF$ unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the correspondence. I need to take a nap now, it's late over here...

Comment: I would say that the 2nd diagram is the answer.

Comment: @user254665 Yes, this is MXYMXY's answer

Comment: Hey, is junior high school=middle school?

Comment: @MXYMXY I'm not sure :) I refer to the dictionary, they own the Chinese meaning “初中".

Comment: Anyway, that school is nice. All my school gives me is horrible calculations.

Comment: @MXYMXY Thanks a lot for your elegant solution. Although now I am a graduate student, I cannot figure out this.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Answers do *not* belong into a question. You can write an answer yourself, or edit an existing answer if you that image would be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am assuming that there is a condition that $\angle DOE=45°$ from your graph.

**HINT**

Note that the set of $O$ such that $\angle DOE=45°$ forms a circle.

And a point on a circle that is farthest away from a fixed point $Q$ holds when the point, the center of the circle, and $Q$ are collinear.

Using this, note the maximum of $\overline {OF}$ holds when $O'D=O'F$.

Computing gives us (credit goes to @AmeetSharma) that the maximum is $$\frac{\overline{DE}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}\overline{DE}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\overline{DE}}{2}= \dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

To generalize, if $\angle DOE=\theta$ then the maximum is $$\frac{\cot \theta}{2}+\frac{\sec \theta}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: Whenever you have time, could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks...

Comment: @imranfat Please see my [**update**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695132/simple-method-to-solve-a-geometry-question-for-junior-high-school-student):)

Comment: Thanks, worth looking into.

Answer (score 13):

Cool problem. Looks like some kind of challenge or tournament problem for junior high students.

[image]

MXYMXY gave the hint. $OF$ passes through the center of the circle for maximum length.

Let $C$ be the center of the circle. $\angle DCE = 2\times\angle DOE = 90^\circ$ (inscribed angle is half central angle)

Let $X$ be the intersection of $DE$ and $OF$.

$\angle DXO$ is a right angle.

$\triangle DCE$ is an isosceles right triangle. $DC = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (this is the radius of the circle)

$\angle DCX = 45^\circ$

$CX = DC \cos(45^\circ) = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$XF = 1\times \sin(60) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$OF = OC+CX+XF =\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\Rightarrow OF = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Answer (score 4):

Practical approach.Take a cardboard in the shape of an equilateral triangle of side 1. Slide two vertices along arms of the $ 45 ^0$ lines,note the other vertex is farthest when the setup is symmetrical, lying along bisector of $45^0 $ corner.

Only new trig ratio to be known is $ \tan 67.5^0$ is $ \sqrt2 +1 $

So the required length is:

$$ \frac12 \; (\tan 60^0 + \tan 67.5^0 ) =\frac {\sqrt3 + \sqrt2 +1}{2}. $$

Answer (score 2):

The hardest step is the first one: guessing the correct answer. By symmetry, it's plausible that $OF$ bisecting $\angle DOE$ will give either a maximum or minimum length. Another likely guess is when $O$, $D$, and $E$ are collinear, but for the given angles of $45^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ that would make $F$ lie outside the angle $DOE$, so "common sense" would eliminate that possibility.

So, how to prove the symmetrical diagram *does* give the longest line? Imagine the triangle $DEF$ is fixed in space. (Note, the diagram given in the question, including the angle $\theta$, is perhaps designed to mislead the student into thinking about $O$ being fixed, and $D$ and $E$ moving).

The locus of points $O'$ such that $\angle DO'E$ is constant is the arc of a circle with chord $DE$ and center $C$ as in @Ameet Sharma's diagram. On the other hand the locus of points $O'$ such that $O'F$ is constant is a circle center $F$. At high school geometry level (and even in Eulid!) is it "obvious" that one circle lies outside the other one, and they have a common tangent at point $O$.

Now that you know the symmetrical figure *is* the solution, calculating the length is simple trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $FX$ be the median of the equilateral triangle such that the length of $FX =$ constant $= [m]$, say

In $\triangle OXF$, $t \le s + [m]$ by triangle inequality.

$t_{max}$ occurs when the triangle is degenerated into a straight line OXF.

When that occurs, $\angle OXD$ has to be right-angled because (1) $OXF$ is a straight line; and (2) $FX$ is the median of the equilateral triangle.

The rod $DE$ should be placed in such a way that (1) $OX$ is the angle bisector of $\angle DOE$; (2) $\triangle ODE$ is isosceles with OD = OE; and (3) it should be perpendicular to $OX$.

The required maximum length $= OX + [m]$ can be easily found and detail is therefore skipped.

Added:-

The required maximum $= OX + [m] = \dfrac {\dfrac {1}{2}}{\tan 22.5^0} +[\dfrac {\sqrt 3}{2}]$

Comment: Thanks a lot:) BTW, I would like to know which software did you use to draw this graph?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I use Geogebra.

Comment: It seems to me that either I'm missing something crucial, or your answer has a gap. Specifically, while it's certainly true that $[m] = FX$ is constant, and that $t = FO \le s + [m]$, with equality only when $O$, $X$ and $F$ are collinear, I don't see anything in your answer to justify the assertion that having those points collinear would necessarily maximize $t$, given that $s = XO$ is *not* a constant.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen We can look at the case from another angle. Let (1) the equilateral triangle be fixed; (2) the red line is hinged with the blue line at O; and (3) both the red and blue lines are movable and extendable. What is the longest length that the red line can be subject to the condition -- $\angle DOE = 45^0$.

Comment: @Mick: Sure, that's essentially the answer given by MXYMXY and Ameet Sharma. But I don't see where you're using that in *your* answer.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen See added.